# Paypal integrated ios app giving error in iTunes

Tags: ios, paypal, app-store-connect

I am facing an issue with uploading an app in iTunes.
Even after I integrated `paypal` with the app, it was working fine. The validation of the app  also succeeded.

After uploading iTunes I get this error message

> There was an error importing this build.View all builds in Activity.
>    ITC.apps.preReleaseBuild.errors.processingFailed

I don't know why this error occurs: [image]

build 4&6 - without paypal sdk, build 5& - with paypal sdk

Comment: @Esq : sorry not solved, not it's on hold